# Display magento new products in specific category

Tags: magento

I need to display new items in magento specific category.

I have found:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_new" name="home.catalog.product.new" alias="product_new" template="catalog/product/new.phtml"}}
```

however it shows store wide items, and also found:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="Category-ID” template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

But it show all products, not only new ones.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use(notice that I changed filename to listnew.phtml):

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="Category-ID" template="catalog/product/listnew.phtml"}}
```

Clone in `root/app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/catalog/product/` `list.phtml` to `listnew.phtml` and replace in it:

```
$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
```

with

```
$_categoryId = $this->getCategoryId();

$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_categoryId)
    ->getProductCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)
    ->addAttributeToFilter(
                array(
                    array('attribute' => 'news_from_date', 'is'=>new Zend_Db_Expr('not null')),
                    array('attribute' => 'news_to_date', 'is'=>new Zend_Db_Expr('not null'))
                    )
                )
    ->setOrder('news_from_date', 'ASC');
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it indeed gives me random items of the selected category, however, I did noticed that some of my items dont show. 

I would like newest items display first, which *I think* is being controlled by news_from_date news_to_date.

I will mark your post as the answer, thank you very much again.

Comment: you can try replace `ASC` with `DESC` or `setOrder('news_from_date', 'ASC');` with `addAttributeToSort('news_from_date', 'DESC');`

Comment: Thanks, ended up replacing the array as I couldn't get more products to be displayed. Hopefully will have  a closer look when I have some more time. Best regards.